# Element in transition inside td relative makes table flicker

Tags: html, css, angularjs, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

Combination of `td{position: relative}`, containing element (`<i>`) with `transition` makes table flicker (borders and background) in **Chrome**(Version 54.0.2840.71 m, windows 10) browser when toggling 1,2,3 in snippet below (borders, background).

**Is this desired behaviour, bug, or can it be solved with some css?**

*(I need position to be there since other code is also relying on it)*

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bodys = [1, 2, 3];
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  position: relative;
}
td{
border-top: 1px solid darkgreen !important;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.glyphicon-chevron-right {
  transition: transform .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggled {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.odd {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body ng-app="app">
  <table ng-controller="testCtrl" class="table">
    <tbody ng-repeat="b in bodys">
      <tr ng-class-even="'odd'">
        <td>{{b}}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="" ng-click="toggled = !toggled">toggle <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ng-class="{'toggled': toggled}"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="toggled" ng-class-even="'odd'">
        <td>{{b + 100}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="toggled" ng-class-even="'odd'">
        <td>{{b + 200}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I see no animation at all.

Comment: there is no animation, only transition on `a` element

Comment: @Terafor: Any particular reason all `table`, all `tr`, and all `td` are set to `position: relative;`?? Remove that and there will be no flicker. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/fg1gmcpe/

Comment: @Abhitalks don't question why, please provide solutions/explanations to question in place

Comment: @Terafor: I am *not* questioning. I am asking. And am doing so because that is important to understand to be able to effect a good solution. And I believe it is important to seek clarifications. Rest is up to you.

Comment: :) @Abhitalks as i pointed out in description other code is relying on td to have position set. in many cases it is another element inside with position absolute. hope this clarifies things

Answer (score 3):

```
.odd td {
  background: gray;
}
```

Should fix it.
Set the transition to 10s. And then you can see that tr is re-rendered and the color is not applied to all columns.

Comment: thanks for input, but it does't solve problem with borders flickering (check the last toggle after toggling in order) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbVPxj

Comment: Hi, yeah I can see the problem. It looks like when the animation is running the other styles are not applied...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's due to the `transform` animation. Make an element `rotate` is calculated with many different ways by browser and here with Chrome, it's like the element isn't in `table` while he's animated...

doesn't work with any other transform property.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bodys = [1, 2, 3];
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  position: relative;
}
td{
border-top: 1px solid darkgreen !important;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*.toggled {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}*/

.odd {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body ng-app="app">
  <table ng-controller="testCtrl" class="table">
    <tbody ng-repeat="b in bodys">
      <tr ng-class-even="'odd'">
        <td>{{b}}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="" id="toggle" ng-click="toggled = !toggled" ng-class="{'toggled': toggled}">toggle</a>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="toggled" ng-class-even="'odd'">
        <td>{{b + 100}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="toggled" ng-class-even="'odd'">
        <td>{{b + 200}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like chrome rendering bug, anyway, <strike>forcing 3d acceleration solve the problem (or at least in my chrome)</strike>.

thats funny, in the code snippet editor, it works, but not working anywhere else.